# Serialize object as element with value of its field

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have a class which needs to be serialized, it has the only 1 field to store a value:

```cs
public class Element
{
     public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And it is saved as(btw: it's not a root element):

```xml
<Element>
     <Value>123</Value>
</Element>
```

However I need to get a bit another xml:

```xml
<Element>123</Element>
```

Serialization is performed using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.
Is there any possibility to omit the **Value**-element and pass its value to **Element**?

Answer (score 1):

Just include `XmlText` attribute. That is all.

```
public class Element
{
    [XmlText]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this and got an error: **Message=Cannot serialize object of type 'Element'. Consider changing type of XmlText member 'Element.Value' from System.Int32 to string or string array.**

Comment: @lamuertepeluda Given your info in the question I copied your `Element` class and used XmlSerializer and got the correct result. So if you get an error, this is not related to the info in your question. Above code works, I don't have a crystal ball to see your desktop.

Comment: yes, well, my fault, forgot to mention - class is derived from base abstract class (e.g.: public class Element : BaseElement) the base class is empty. Yes, without extension - [XmlText] works.

Comment: @lamuertepeluda then declare value as `[XmlText] 
        public string Value { get; set; }` like your error message suggests. It will work